# How to proxy and get external resources (e.g. get bootstrap and jquery resources)

Tags: gulp, browser-sync

I'm trying to use browser-sync with gulp to proxy and it can't get external resources like bootstrap and jquery files on their cdn.
Locally it's working, but external resources don't:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

My gulpfile.js browser-sync configuratin proxying to my tomcat:

```
gulp.task('server', function(){
    browserSync.init({
        proxy: "http://localhost:8080/"
    });
});
```